# В битриксе не работают JS-скрипты для неавторизованных пользователей

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В у нас в интернет-магазине есть мини-слайдер на карточке товара. Он работает только тогда, когда пользователь авторизован. Если пользователь не авторизован, тогда скрипт может немного поработать на время загрузки страницы, а после полной загрузки страницы он перестает работать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, нужно инициализировать соответствующие расширения:

```
CJSCore::Init('date');
CJSCore::Init('ajax');
CJSCore::Init('jquery2');
```

Либо для неавторизованного пользователя возникает ошибка в одном из блоков `$(document).ready()`, из-за чего последующие подобные блоки не выполняются.

Comment: Помогло решение для $(document).ready(). Но теперь интересно, почему именно у неавторизованных пользователей возникает эта ошибка? Как $(document).ready() влияет на авторизованных пользователей?

Comment: Скорее всего, на странице для неавторизованного пользователя нет какого-то элемента, на наличие которого расчитывает скрипт.